# Error: Type is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor

Tags: angular, promise

I've written this function in TypeScript:

```js
export class LoginService {

  async isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const r = await this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/user/isLoggedIn').toPromise();
    return r.body;
  }
}
```

When I try to run the Angular 6 application, I'm getting this error message:

ERROR in src/app/login.service.ts(28,23): error TS1055: Type 'boolean' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.

I've used async/await in other applications before without hitting this before.

UPDATE:
The question I would like answered is: how do I get the "isLoggedIn" function to return a boolean?

Answer (score 97):

An `async` function can ONLY return a promise by definition - all `async` functions return promises.  It can't return a boolean.

That's what TypeScript is telling you.  The `async` function can return a promise that resolves to a boolean.

The value that you `return` inside your `async` function becomes the resolved value of the promise that the `async` function returns.  So, the return type for your `async` function is a promise (that resolves to a boolean).

The caller of `isLoggedIn()` will have to either use `.then()` with it or `await` with it.

```
export class LoginService {

    async isLoggedIn(): Promise<any> {
      const r = await this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/user/isLoggedIn').toPromise();
      return r.body;
    }

}
```

Comment: But why can't I just use await inside the "isLoggedIn()" function and return a boolean? But I can't use await unless I use async? But I can't return a boolean if I use async? Seems a bit catch-22?

Comment: You can use await only in the async function which will return promise. We are saying to javascript, its a asynchronous  function which will return based on API response.

Comment: ok Thanks for your response. I updated my question to reflect more accurately what I'm actually trying to do. Basically the function does an asynchronous api call and I want it to wait/block until it gets a concrete value (boolean) and then return the boolean value. Not a promise.

Comment: @user275801 - Because that's not how async functions work.  await only pauses execution inside the function, not outside it.  You need to read a lot more about how async functions work.  All async functions return a promise, not your value.  That's how it works.

Comment: @user275801 - You can't do that in javascript.  Async values are communicated via callbacks or promises.  await only simplifies things inside the function, not outside the function.  Seriously, read more about async functions.

Comment: so, let me get this straight... you're saying that given these premises:

1. There's an API function "isLoggedIn" running on a server which returns a boolean.
2. The client side JS can communicate with the server and makes the API call.
3. The server replies with a boolean value
4. The client side gets the boolean value and turns it into a promise.
5. It's impossible to get the boolean value out again?

Really?

Comment: Basically the question is: how do I get the "isLoggedIn" function to return a boolean?

Comment: @user275801 - As I've already said, you use `await` or `.then()` with the returned promise.  `xxx.isLoggedIn().then(bool => { /* use the value here */})`.  See [How do I return response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) for more info and read more about functions declared with the `async` keyword.

Comment: You may need to upgrade to ES6. It explicitly states [here](https://javascript.info/async-await#await) that you are correct in your assumptions. Otherwise, why bother with await and just return the dam promise immediately!

Comment: @Ian Thank you, that is very interesting about ES6. I have since then understood better how to use promises. but I do think the ES6 spec is what most people (beginners) would expect promises to work.

Answer (score 14):

If your endpoint `/api/user/isLoggedIn` returns only a boolean value, you should just be able to use below by casting the http get method. But indeed you can only return a promise from an async function.

```
export class LoginService {
  async isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<boolean>('http://localhost:3000/api/user/isLoggedIn').toPromise();
  }
}
```

You could have an async function that consumes `isLoggedIn()` like this:

```
async doSomething() {
  const loggedIn: boolean = await service.isLoggedIn();
  if (loggedIn) {
    doThis();
  }    
}
```

Which would be called like this

```
await doSomething();
```

Answer (score 4):

The return type should be Promise

```
/* sync */ isLoggedIn(): boolean
async isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean>
```

async functions return a Promise (mandatory by virtue of being async), and you indicate that the promise will resolve to a boolean

Answer (score 4):

Since this question has a huge amount of views, I'll provide a more broad type of (possible) solution ... if you're able to update your `tsconfig` file's `target` value to something more modern you won't get the error anymore.

In my case:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
     ...
  }
}
```

Just make sure your project can still build / start and everything is fine before you continue on.